# Google Maps API info window wont open

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I use Google Maps on my website and it works fine. But if i use a own marker image, then the info window won't pop up anymore. Anybody a idea why?

You can see the whole project without my own marker at https://www.hauskataloge24.de/index.php?id=6

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: {lat: 50.984768, lng: 11.029880}
    });

    setMarkers(map);
}

var musters = <?php echo json_encode($musters); ?>;

function setMarkers(map) {
    var image = {
        url: 'img/markerBlue.png'
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < musters.length; i++) {
        var muster = musters[i];
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); /* SINGLE */

        var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: muster[1], lng: muster[2]},
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: muster[0]
        });

        placeMarker(muster);

        function placeMarker(loc) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( loc[1], loc[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latLng,
                map      : map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
                infowindow.setContent( "<div id='infowindow'>"+ loc[3] +"</div>");
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey dude thanks for your help. It was not what i was looking for, but it helped me to find the solution. Thx.

I've forgotten to add the icon in my function placeMarker()

Now i got it and it works fine. Thank you :-)

```
        function placeMarker(loc) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( loc[1], loc[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latLng,
                icon: icons.icon,
                map      : map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
                infowindow.setContent( "<div id='infowindow'>"+ loc[3] +"</div>");
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation on custom markers here that includes a JSFiddle example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

I've modified the sample in the above doc to have an infowindow come up whenever a marker is pressed. Please see my fiddle here(NOTE: You will need to add your API key to the code for it to work, I removed mine for security):

https://jsfiddle.net/tmgz0vau/

Code sample for the custom marker icons:

```
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
var icons = {
  parking: {
    icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
  },
  library: {
    icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
  },
  info: {
    icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
  }
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'this is a test'
});

function addMarker(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

var features = [
  {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.22630),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91539, 151.22820),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91747, 151.22912),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91910, 151.22907),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91725, 151.23011),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91872, 151.23089),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91784, 151.23094),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91682, 151.23149),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91790, 151.23463),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91666, 151.23468),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.916988, 151.233640),
    type: 'info'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91662347903106, 151.22879464019775),
    type: 'parking'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.916365282092855, 151.22937399734496),
    type: 'parking'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91665018901448, 151.2282474695587),
    type: 'parking'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.919543720969806, 151.23112279762267),
    type: 'parking'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91608037421864, 151.23288232673644),
    type: 'parking'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91851096391805, 151.2344058214569),
    type: 'parking'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91818154739766, 151.2346203981781),
    type: 'parking'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91727341958453, 151.23348314155578),
    type: 'library'
  }
];

for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
  addMarker(feature);
}
```

I hope this helps!